# How to fetch latitude and longitude data from city name and zipcode

Tags: r, geolocation, gis, latitude-longitude

I am looking for a way to get latitude and longitude coordinates form an indian zip code in R.

My data frame looks like:

```
Area       Zip   
Mumbai    410710
Mumbai    400083
Mumbai    400034
Mumbai    400612
```

Looking to get:

```
Area       Zip         Latitude     Longitude
Mumbai    410710        ...           ...
Mumbai    400083
Mumbai    400034
Mumbai    400612
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggmap::geocode`.

```
library(ggmap)    

zip <- read.table(text = "Area       Zip   
    Mumbai    410710
    Mumbai    400083
    Mumbai    400034
    Mumbai    400612", header = T)

gc <- do.call(rbind,
        apply(zip, 1, function(x){geocode(location = paste(x[2], x[1], sep = ", "), 
                                          source = "google")})
        )
cbind(zip, gc)
#     Area    Zip      lon      lat
# 1 Mumbai 410710 72.87766 19.07598
# 2 Mumbai 400083 72.93742 19.11662
# 3 Mumbai 400034 72.81482 18.97242
# 4 Mumbai 400612 73.02872 19.17993
```

However, sometimes the Google API seems to return `NA` for no reason. Therefore, you might have to loop through it until no `NA` is contained anymore.
Or use `source = "dsk"`. However, the datasciencetoolkit might not have long lat for all these zip codes.

Comment: When I try to run the above code it gives me following error -

Comment: are you able to run `apply(zip, 1, function(x){geocode(location = paste(x[2], x[1], sep = ", "), source = "google")})`?

Comment: Error in geocode(location = paste(x[2], x[1], sep = ", "), source = "google") : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the error. Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48665558/edit) the output of `sessionInfo()` to your Q.

Comment: @loki is there a way to get the lat and long from just the zip?